# jQuery equivalent of getting the context of a Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have the following working code:

```
ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
```

Is there any way to re-write it to use `$`? Doing this fails:

```
ctx = $("#canvas").getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');
```

jQuery exposes the actual DOM element in numeric indexes, where you can perform normal JavaScript/DOM functions.

Answer (score 17):

I have also seen that it's often preferred to use .get(0) to reference a jquery target as HTML element:

```
var myCanvasElem = $("#canvas").get(0);
```

Perhaps to help avoid any potential null object references since jquery returns null as an object but working with the element from .get(0) may not fail so silently...  You can easily check if the canvas was found first before .get(0) like

```
if( $("#canvas").length ) ctx = $("#canvas").get(0).getContext('2d');
else console.log('Error: Canvas not found with selector #canvas');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try{ 
   ctx = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
}catch(e){ 
    console.log('We have encountered an error: ' + e);
}
```

or...

```
if( typeof $('#canvas') === 'undefined'){ 
    var canvas = '<canvas id="canvas"><\/canvas>';
    $('body').append(canvas);
}
setTimeout( function(){ ctx = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d'); }, 500);
```

Using setTimeout is an easy way to ensure you don't try calling the canvas element before it's fully created and registered to the DOM.

Comment: This question was asked 8 years before you answered. Check the date it was asked before answering!

Comment: I'm not sure why adding another relevant answer to an "old" question is a bad thing. This site is a resource for current and future users. Google serves the old questions to current users all the time. so if we land on them, we should keep them up to date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

let ctx = $('canvas')[0]

Answer (score -6):

The script works before it finds "canvas"

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   ctx = $("#canvas");
});
```