# how to get an dom element into a variable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm playing with a beginners tutorial about canvas

I was wondering if i can change this(which works straight from the tutorial):

```
     <script>  
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
        });  
    </script>
```

into this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    can = $("mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
 });
```

or maybe even into

```
var ctx=$("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(50,25,150,100);
```

something doesn't work and I can't figure out what?
I tried adding .val() as i saw in countless articles

```
can=$("#mycanvas").val()
```

and also .atrr()

```
can=$("mycanvas").attr("id")
```

but to no avail
what am i doing wrong? or maybe it isn't possible with jquery?
I would be glad for any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `.attr('id')`, not `.atrr('id')`.

To get the DOM node from a jQuery object, use the array subscript operator (`[]`) or the `.get()` method:

```
var can = $('#mycanvas')[0]; // or:
var can = $('#mycanvas').get(0);
```

Comment: and now it seems to work.. don't know what was wrong before - actually this also works: var ctx =$("#mycanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
and another link to the same problem I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925130/jquery-equivalent-of-getting-the-context-of-a-canvas/2925139#2925139