# How to load image To HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on the below demo. Why am I not able to load the image into HTML canvas?

I am getting this error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: c.getContext is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 24,
  "colno": 17
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expose = function() {
    var c = $("#myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = $("#scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  };
  setTimeout(expose, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well because JQuery returns an object that contains the DOM elements, and using `#myCanvas` doesn't actually select the DOM element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expose = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  };
  setTimeout(expose, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make two changes:

```
var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById('scream');
```

For the first:
[jQuery equivalent of getting the context of a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925130/jquery-equivalent-of-getting-the-context-of-a-canvas)

And for the second, is expected you to pass an CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas, jQuery returns a jQuery object not a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expose = function() {
    var c = $("#myCanvas");
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    var img = $("#scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  };
  setTimeout(expose, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: It's an issue with your image.Lemme check but I'm queit sure it's all about the image.Change the image and it should work and moreover the error will be there in the log only and not displayed to the user.

Comment: It should be img[0] because the JQuery doesn't select the DOM element, it returns an object which has the DOM Object

Comment: This question will solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918791/quaggajs-failed-to-execute-drawimage