# Draw image in canvas with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

```
$.fn.colorPicker = function () {
    const $div = this;
    const $colorPickerIcon = $("<img></img");
    const $canvas = $("<canvas></canvas>").addClass("canvas");
    const $context = $canvas.getContext("2d");
    const $closeButton = new Image();
    $closeButton.src = "./imgs/close.png";
    $($colorPickerIcon).attr("src", "./imgs/icon.jpg").attr("id", "icon").appendTo($div);
    $($colorPickerIcon).on("click", function () {
        $($colorPickerIcon).hide();
        $($closeButton).on("load", function () {
            $context.drawImage($closeButton, 0, 0);
        });
    });
}
```

I tried this code and after many changes I decide to question for solution here. I have a problem with getting context. I always recieve this mistake "TypeError: $canvas.getContext is not a function". I used [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) article to program this, but it's still not working.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925139

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery equivalent of getting the context of a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925130/jquery-equivalent-of-getting-the-context-of-a-canvas)

Comment: as far as I know `getContext("2d")` is not a `jQuery` function but a `JavaScript`. In order to get what you desired use `const $context = $canvas[0]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the `getContext`-Method of a jQuery Object. But `getContext` is a method of HTMLCanvasElement which is accessible under `$('<canvas></canvas>')[0].getContext("2d")`

Comment: you can find it inside the `__proto__`-method when you `console.log($('<canvas></canvas>')[0])`