# How do I run canvas.getContext() using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use `getContext('2d');` using jQuery. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925130/jquery-equivalent-of-getting-the-context-of-a-canvas),
but it doesn't seem to work. It could possibly be from updates, since the question was asked near 9 years ago. I am adding `<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>` in the head, but using a different `<script>` tag for my javascript (shouldn't be a problem). Here is all of my code:

```js
var c = $('.canvas');
var ctx = $(c)[0].getContext('2d');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas'>You're browser does not support the requirements to play this game. Update your browser or use a different browser</canvas>
```

I'm using Google and checking the console through F12, and it says -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That error has nothing to do with `getContext` itself. It's saying that `$(c)[0]` is undefined. Please share your relevant HTML.

Comment: @Tyler I edited the question and added all of my code :)

Comment: The question you reference actually answers your question. You didn't follow the instructions correctly: `var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');`

Comment: @ibu can you explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: You wrote `$(c)`, use the code in my example or any of the answers below.

Comment: I saw Tyler's answer which helped me, thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$(".canvas")` selects all elements with a *class* of "canvas". You do not have any elements that satisfy this selector, as your `<canvas>` doesn't have any `class` on it at all.

   You could either use `$("#canvas")` to select by `id`, or `$("canvas")` to select by node type (`<canvas>`).
2. `var c` is already a jQuery object - no need to re-wrap it in `$(...)`
3. This is only a hunch based on your `window.onload`, but if your script is not at the end of the `<body>` *or* it's in the `<head>` but not wrapped in a `$(document).ready( ... )`, the code will look for the `<canvas>` element before it exists.

```
$(document).ready(function() {              // Remove this line if your code is at the end of <body>
    var $c = $('#canvas');
    var ctx = $c.get(0).getContext('2d');
});                                         // Remove this line if your code is at the end of <body>
```

I've changed `var c` to `var $c` and `[0]` to `.get(0)` strictly on the basis of personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from some sort of explanation, or at the very least you could acknowledge OP's error.

Comment: This is pretty much the same code I had, except for the fact you changed (c) to ('#canvas')....