# Check if canvas is not empty

Tags: jquery

I have 3 signature boxes on a page and I'm trying to check if they are empty/blank.

I tried `$('#input_5_9').val() == ''` but it doesn't detect anything.
When I interact with the canvas nothing changes in the `HTML`.

The `HTML` for the canvas is:

```html
<canvas id="input_5_9" width="300" height="180" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: dashed; border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: url(&quot;https://website.com/super_signature/pen.cur&quot;), pointer; width: 300px; height: 180px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925130/jquery-equivalent-of-getting-the-context-of-a-canvas

Comment: When the signature is placed in to the `canvas` what does the HTML look like? Is a `path` or some other element appended to the `canvas`? I would assume you just need to use the `:empty` selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check `number of nested object in canvas`, you can use `$('#input_5_9').children().length` to check is empty or not.

```js
if($('#input_5_9').children().length == 0)
  console.log("canvas is empty");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="input_5_9" width="300" height="180" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: dashed; border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
cursor: url(&quot;https://website.com/super_signature/pen.cur&quot;), pointer; width: 300px; height: 180px;">
    </canvas>
```